# Объединение нескольких массивов

Tags: php, массивы

Как 3 массива

```
$x = array(12, 16, 18);
$y = array(22, 26, 28);
$z = array(32, 36, 38);
```

можно объединить в один?

```
$xyz = array(12, 22, 32, 16, 26, 36, 18, 28, 38);
```

Comment: порядок важен ?

Comment: @Etki судя по `$xyz`, сначала берутся первые элементы массивов, потом вторые, и т.д.

Comment: @Regent, ну право дело, ну.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Главное условие - длина всех массивов равна.

```
$x = array(12, 16, 18);
$y = array(22, 26, 28);
$z = array(32, 36, 38);
$xyz = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($x); $i++) {
    $xyz[] = $x[$i];
    $xyz[] = $y[$i];
    $xyz[] = $z[$i];
}
print_r($xyz);
```

[Пример на ideone.com](http://ideone.com/7EfoAJ)

Comment: Отчего бы не предусмотреть разную длину? [Ideone](http://ideone.com/At3CKW)

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array_merge_recursive($x, $y, $z);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 16
    [2] => 18
    [3] => 22
    [4] => 26
    [5] => 28
    [6] => 32
    [7] => 36
    [8] => 38
)
```

Comment: Результат не похож на результат в вопросе.

Comment: В вопросе не указано точно, что именно так должен выглядеть результирующий массив. Решать автору вопроса, может его устроит, за него пока решать нет смысла